# apt-file can not find a dkms file

Tags: debian, dpkg, locate, apt-file

Before I upgrade to Debian Bullseye, `apt-file` was pretty logical. Now I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Did the behavior change?

```
# apt-file update
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                                                                        
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease               
Hit:5 https://packages.riot.im/debian default InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
9 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Prove the file is there...

```
# locate v4l2loopback.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.6.0-1-amd64/updates/dkms/v4l2loopback.ko
/var/lib/dkms/v4l2loopback/0.12.5/5.6.0-1-amd64/x86_64/module/v4l2loopback.ko
```

`apt-file` can't tell me what package provides it:

```
# apt-file search v4l2loopback.ko
... nothing...
```

What package provides `v4l2loopback.ko`? How can I find it out? Did the behavior of `apt-file` change?

---

Dpkg also can't find it.

```
# dpkg -S /usr/lib/modules/5.6.0-1-amd64/updates/dkms/v4l2loopback.ko
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/modules/5.6.0-1-amd64/updates/dkms/v4l2loopback.ko
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mention of `dkms` in the path is important: `dkms` is the "Dynamic Kernel Module Support (DKMS)" system. Those kernel modules were built on your system using files provided by some packages; they are not provided directly by those packages and so are not owned by those packages. So, neither `apt-file` nor `dpkg` can help; maybe the `dkms` command can.